# AndroidStudio - NavigationDrawer and CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, custom-adapter

I have created a new project using `AndroidStudio` and I have included the `NavigationDrawer` that comes from with the IDE.
I would like to modify the `Navigation` that comes from the left side and add two `TextView`, one will hold the menu text and the second will hold just a letter right now.

So I have create a class to manage my custom menu:

```
public class MioMenu{
    private String voce;
    private String immagine;

    public MioMenu(String immagine, String voce){
        this.immagine = immagine;
        this.voce = voce;
    }

    public String getVoce(){
        return this.voce;
    }

    public String getImmagine(){
        return this.immagine;
    }
}
```

Then I have created my `CustomAdapter` and override the `getView` method:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MioMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MioMenu>{

    public MioMenuAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, MioMenu[] objects){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_menu_laterale, null);
        TextView icona = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconaCustom);
        TextView testo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testoCustom);

        MioMenu mm = getItem(position);
        icona.setText(mm.getImmagine());
        testo.setText(mm.getVoce());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And this is my custom_layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iconaCustom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#00AA00"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testoCustom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#00AA00"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I have edited the `onCreateView` in the `NavigationDrawerFragment.java` created by default with the IDE:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        //Creo una nuova lista che conterrà i miei dati per generare il menu
        List list = new LinkedList();

        //Creo le voci
        list.add(new MioMenu("a", getString(R.string.title_section1)));
        list.add(new MioMenu("b", getString(R.string.title_section2)));
        list.add(new MioMenu("c", getString(R.string.title_section3)));
        list.add(new MioMenu("d", getString(R.string.title_section4)));
        list.add(new MioMenu("e", getString(R.string.title_section5)));
        list.add(new MioMenu("f", getString(R.string.title_section6)));

        /*mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                android.R.id.text1,
                //Elenco voci del menu laterale
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                        getString(R.string.title_section4),
                        getString(R.string.title_section5),
                        getString(R.string.title_section6),
                }));
           */

        MioMenuAdapter mio_adapter = new MioMenuAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_row_menu_laterale, list);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(mio_adapter);

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }
```

As you can see I have commented out the `setAdapter` and I have create a `List` to save my custom object and then pass it to my custom adapter but the IDE stops me with a red line under

```
MioMenuAdapter mio_adapter = new MioMenuAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_row_menu_laterale, list);
```

With this error:

[image]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here

Comment: third parameter in Adapter must be the array not List or make changes in Adapter to make it List and let me know if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes in your Adapter and pass List as third parameter or remove it from constructor because I am not seeing your are using it at all anywhere in your adapter. Might be that is also a mistake of yours, So If you want to use your list as well which you have passed  in your constructor your Adapter implementation should be something like given below :

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MioMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MioMenu>{

 List list;

public MioMenuAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List myList){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    list=myList;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_menu_laterale, null);
    TextView icona = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconaCustom);
    TextView testo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testoCustom);

    MioMenu mm = list.get(position);
    icona.setText(mm.getImmagine());
    testo.setText(mm.getVoce());

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I totaly miss it